# C&C4 says I need more command posts / points

Tags: command-and-conquer-4

Playing C&C4. When I try to build beyond my unit cap (50) there is a female voice that says, "We need more command posts [or is it:'points'?]." How can I capture more? How can I get the unit cap beyond 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command points are a built-in limit to the number of units you can have at one time. In general gameplay, there is no way to breach the cap - it's 50 command points no matter what you do.

However, if you're not adverse to doing a little bit of modding, you can increase the number of command points on a per-map basis:

> So I have seen a few people ask about
>   this, so I thought I would make a
>   quick tutorial for it.  It is possible
>   to increase the number of command
>   points available for a specific map in
>   C&C Tiberian Twilight.  At this point
>   it is not possible to mod the command
>   points globally(I think?).
>
> To access the scripts interface, go
>   to, Edit->Scripts
>
> The script should go under
>   "PlyrCivilian"  The script required is
>   under the heading "ThreeSixty",(this
>   goes under the "Actions If True" tab) 
>   and the script you want is "Override
>   player command points".  Set the
>   values of "total" and "Maximum" to the
>   number of command points you want.
>
> ...and thats it.
>
> the finished script should look like
>   this:

```
 **If**

  True 

 **Then**  

 Override command points for player <AllPlayers> to total:X> Maximum:X
```

> (Where x is the pop cap you want)
>
> It is possible to extract the maps
>   that come with the game, by extracting
>   the .map files from Maps.big, using
>   OSBig, and then modify them with World
>   Builder.

Comment: where is edit ?
i didnt found it in my game folder

Answer (score 1):

Use cheat engine. First, open the CNC 4 process and enter the value of your command points then press new scan. Now change the number command points you have from the game and press next scan. Keep doing this until you get 2 values in the scan list.

Double click on the value and then it will go to the table below. Double click on the value over there and change the value to zero.